# BigQuery Convert RFC 1123 Date Format String to unixtime

Tags: google-bigquery

I am parsing some HTTP Header fields and my input is a RFC 1123 formatted date time. For example: "Wed, 21 Nov 2012 23:10:20 GMT"

I need to convert the above string to the standard TIMESTAMP date type in BigQuery which means I need to convert it to  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.uuuuuu]. I am wondering whats the best way to move forward. My initial approach is to use REGEXP_REPLACE a bunch of times but I am sure there is a better way.

The input format using [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) format would be '%a,%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S' that needs to be transformed somehow to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Let me know

Comment: What backend language you use?

Comment: This is about BigQuery so the answer is SQL supported here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can do something like this:

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser
date_object = parser.parse('Wed, 21 Nov 2012 23:10:20 GMT')
date_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT')
```

Comment: Thank you. Python or any other language wouldnt simply work: To reframe it just using the nouns/verbs listed here using SQL: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Answer (score 1):

Overly-complicated way to resolve this in SQL:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(date, 13, 4)+'/'+month_number+'/'+SUBSTR(date, 6, 2)+' '+SUBSTR(date, 18, 8)) ts
FROM
  (SELECT 'Wed, 21 Aug 2012 23:10:20 GMT' date) a
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT STRING(POSITION(month)) month_number, month FROM (SELECT SPLIT(months) month
   FROM (SELECT 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec' months))) b
WHERE SUBSTR(date, 9, 3)=b.month
```

Replace `(SELECT 'Wed, 21 Aug 2012 23:10:20 GMT' date)` with your own table.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a tedious but working solution in the following SQL which I am sure has great opportunities to make it more efficient

```
    select DATE(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
         regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
               regexp_replace(<insert_date>,
                           r'(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)[,] ',''),
            r' GMT',''),
         r'Jan', '01'),
         r'Feb', '02'),
         r'Mar', '03'),
         r'Apr', '04'),
         r'May', '05'),
         r'Jun', '06'),
         r'Jul', '07'),
         r'Aug', '08'),
         r'Sep', '09'),
         r'Oct', '10'),
         r'Nov', '11'),
         r'Dec', '12'),
         r'(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)',r'\3-\2-\1 \4'))
         from <table>;
```

Comment: I found this now http://bigqueri.es/t/is-expiration-window-commensurate-with-the-resource-change-rate/316, nice :)

Comment: Yes, That was my end goal whereas this query was the first subproblem to get there